# rosjava actionlib

Tags: actionlib, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was wondering why the rosjava implementation of actionlib is not included in the latest rosjava revision anymore? Back in April it was still part of the repository and I would like to ask, if anyone knows whether actionlib will be supported (again) in the future or not?

Best Regards,

Sebastian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37198/rosjava-actionlib/) by [ch1bo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2553/ch1bo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some major changes to rosjava that broke the existing implementation of actionlib. The intent was always to rewrite the existing rosjava actionlib anyway so the old version was removed pending an eventual rewrite.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1